# $A$ be a $5\times 5$ real matrix $\ni$ each row sum is $1$, then each row sum of the matrix $A^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ be a $5\times 5$ real matrix $\ni$ each row sum is $1$, then I need to know the sum of all entries  the matrix $A^3$

Well, I have no clue. One thing I realise that the matrix will have $1$ as an eigen value with corresponding eigen vector $(1,\dots,1)^t$

Thanks. Here row sum I mean $a_{11}+\dots+a_{15}=1$

Comment: What does that $\;\ni\;$ there mean??

Comment: Really?! Never saw it before...Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A (1,\ldots,1)^t = (1,\ldots,1)^t$ we also have $A^n (1,\ldots,1)^t = (1,\ldots,1)^t$. But the elements of $A^n(1,\ldots,1)^t$ are exactly the row sums of $A^n$!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$A=(a_{ij})\implies A^2=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{kj}\right)$$

and the sum of the rows of $\;A^2\;$ is

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}a_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}\sum_{j=1}^na_{kj}=1\cdot 1=1$$

Generalize.